# Check whether URLs are up or down using Java

Tags: java

I have a list of 20-30 URLs which need to be checked using a Java program whether they are up or down. The URLs before opening require entering of username/password by the user which has to automated.

I am not able to decide what to use for this.

Comment: Does it have to be specifically a java program? You might have an easier time with a scripting language.

Comment: Actually I was working on a J2EE project and had to integrate this sanity check with it so gave emphasis to Java program. Can u please help with any scripting language also. I will check if it might help.

Comment: Just to clarify: Upon pinging a URL, you will know whether it is up or not, without even attempting to login. Or do you wish to know if the login was successful. 

Otherwise you could just use isReachable()http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Comment: I also want to know whether Login was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

If these URls are under you control, then the best way to do this (IMO) is to expose a status endpoint on each of these URLs, so that you can invoke this via HttpGet and get the system status of these endpoints. If these URLs are not under your control, its best to find out from the URL owners for an outage schedule. You could potentially do a GET on them and inspect the response, but the URL owners might decide to just block your calls.

Comment: These urls are my own. I need to do a sanity check for all urls whenever any update is done. I need to automate this sanity check. Can u please elaborate a bit more. Thanks

Comment: If these URLs belong to you, you can add a status check endpoint, for e.g. http://yourdomain/status_check , so that you can just do a HTTP GET on /status_check from your java code, which would return some response to you indicating what is happening with the system.

Comment: Okay I got you, but I think that will not work as urls require entering of username/password to proceed further. I would not like entering username/password for all urls for checking whether they are up or down.

Comment: Well, the status check endpoint should not require a username/password, it should be a URL which doesn't fall under the same constraints as other URLs under that domain.